# How to install an application for personal private use

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, installation, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows 8 phone, and I've made an application for myself, which I don't want to make public. I just want to install my program on my own phone. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio, open the project for your application.

Set the phone application as the startup project.

Connect your phone to your computer.

On the debug button (the green play button in the toolbar) click the down arrow to see the debugging options for the project.

Make sure your phone is on and unlocked (on the home screen).

Select `Device`.

You can click the debug button now (which should read `Device`) and your app will then be installed on your phone and debugging will start.

You could also press `CTRL + F5` or select `Start Without Debugging` from the `Debug` menu to install and launch the app on your phone.

Whichever route you take, the app will not be uninstalled from your phone when you're done, you'll be able to go on using it however you like.

Comment: I'll try this soon, and let you know how it goes

Comment: From what I can see, I still need to developer unlock the phone.

Comment: How can I get a private testing account, without the ability to submit to the store? Something that doesn't involve $100

Comment: I'm looking into options right now, though I think the most promising would be getting in touch with the Windows Phone evangelist in your area and seeing if they can hook you up.

Comment: About the best I can find is BizSpark (http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx) or DreamSpark (https://www.dreamspark.com/) (depending on what you qualify for)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. After developing the application, you can install it using windows
   phone SDK for testing purpose. And you can keep testing forever :-)
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg588378(v=vs.105).aspx
2. Publish it under beta program, you have option to restrict downloads to only users having the specific download link. And you dont share it with anyone else!

Comment: How can I get a private testing account, without the ability to submit to the store? Something that doesn't involve $100

Comment: i am afraid there is no way to get around $100 :-( If you are a student, you can go for the DreamSpark way of MSDN subscription. Otherwise, pretty much you will need and windows phone dev center account to be able to do this.

Comment: What if I don't want to deploy it to the store, just install it on my own phone. I'm not paying microsoft for an application that I made.

Comment: Similar to the way Apple has done this, you cannot install an application on your own device without using a developer account.